# Can emmeans apply sphericity corrections to repeated-measures contrasts?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, emmeans

I am analysing a 2-way repeated-measures dataset, modelled as follows:

```
model= lmer(result ~ treatment * time + (1|subject), data=df)
```

... where every subject receives every treatment and is tested at every time. However when analysing the contrasts, there appears to be no correction for sphericity. Here I am using emmeans to test for a difference between each treatment and the control-treatment, at each level of "time"...

```
emm <- emmeans(model,c("treatment","time")
contrast(emm, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref="Control", by="time")
```

When I look at the output from contrast(), I confirmed there is no G-G correction by comparing with the output from GraphPad Prism for the same dataset.

Is there a simple way of achieving a sphericity-corrected analysis of the contrasts?

Comment: `emmeans` does not analyze your data; it interprets your model. The model you fitted incorporates very simple homogeneity assumptions. If you think your model is right, them the EMMs and contrasts are right. But if you think those are wrong, you need a different model that accounts for whatever irregularities you are concerned about. Maybe a multivariate model?

Comment: I would recommend asking on stats.stackexchange.com. Heteroscedastic residuals in the context of a multilevel regression is a tough one, and you may get better insights on the other site.

Comment: I agree with @Simon that better advice on modeling issues would be available on CV. In case I was too dismissive in my comment, I'll add that you might take a look at the **afex** package. Its `aov_ez` function (or some similar name) will fit BOTH the univariate and multivariate model, provides guidance on which is better, and supports post hoc tests via **emmeans** for whichever you decide to use.

Comment: I do appreciate the comments and thank you. I'll repost and check afex - it sounds like it was designed for these kinds of experiments. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thank's to the commentors for identifying this solution. the afex() packages is specifically designed for repeated measures factorial designs, and allows the appropriate corrections.

- aov_ez (in the afex package) automatically applies corrections for non-sphericity
- emmeans should specify that the model is multivariate
- contrast (in the emmeans package) should specify the appropriate adjustment to "p"

The solution therefore would look like this...

```
library(afex)
library(emmeans)

model= aov_ez("subject","result",df,within=c("treatment","time"),type="III")
emm= emmeans(model,c("treatment","time"),model="multivariate")
contrast(emm,"trt.vs.ctrl",ref="Control",by="time",adjust="dunn")
```

Hope this is helpful for anyone else with a similar question!